# VUE CLI no carga "EJECUTAR TAREA" ni muestra errores, todo mi trabajo estancado!

Tags: vuejs

Estoy creando una aplicación con VUE CLI y VUETIFY esta app consume api de WORDPRESS. Al principio todo normal pero luego demoraba en cargar al "EJECUTAR TAREA", pero desde hace un día que intento ejecutar y nada se queda paralizado, siempre en 44% - 48%, he intentando varias cosas y nada.

Entorno: WINDOWS 10
Puertos: Vue cli :8000
api wordpress: :80

**NUEVA ACTUALIZACIÓN**

- Ahora he comprobado que carga cuando no importo ningún componente.

Así esta hecho mi componente y la vista donde los importo.

```
/*ESTE ES MI COMPONENTE*/    
<template>
      <div class="listaNoticias" v-if="loading">
        <v-card class="elevation-light">
          <v-card-title class="title pb-0">POPULAR</v-card-title>
          <v-list-item v-for="(item,i) in listpost" :key="i" class="px-5 py-1">
            <v-list-item-avatar size="80">
              <v-img
                v-if="item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']"
                :src="item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url"
                :lazy-src="item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url"
              >
                <v-icon
                  v-if="item.format != 'standard'"
                  class="iconCard small"
                  color="white"
                >{{ iconsCard[item.format] }}</v-icon>
              </v-img>
            </v-list-item-avatar>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <router-link :to="`/${item.slug}`">
                <v-card-title
                  :class="(isMobile)?'body-2':'subtitle-2'"
                  class="pa-0"
                >{{ item.title.rendered }}</v-card-title>
              </router-link>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-card>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import axios from "axios";
    import { mapState } from "vuex";

    export default {
      name: "ListaNoticias",
      props: {
        categories: {
          value: Number,
          required: true
        },
        exclude: {
          value: Number,
          required: true
        }
      },
      data: () => ({
        listpost: [],
        loading: false,
        error: false
      }),
      computed: {
        isMobile() {
          return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.width <= 768;
        },
        ...mapState(["urlApi", "iconsCard"])
      },
      methods: {
        async getListPost() {
          await axios
            .get(
              `${this.urlApi}posts/?exclude=${this.$props.exclude}&_embed&per_page=8&categories=${this.$props.categories}`
            )
            .then(res => {
              this.listpost = res.data;
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
              this.error=true;
            })
            .finally(() => (this.loading = true));
        }
      },

      mounted() {
        this.getListPost();
      }
    };
    </script>

    <style lang="scss">
    .listaNoticias {
      .v-card__title {
        word-break: normal !important;
      }
    }
    </style>

/*ESTA ES MI VISTA DONDE LO IMPORTO*/
<template>
      <div class="post">
       <v-card class="elevation-0" v-if="loading">
          <div v-if="laodingCategories" class="ml-4">
            <v-btn
              text
              small
              class="mt-2"
              v-for="(cat, i) in post.categories"
              :key="i"
            >{{ categorias[cat].name }}</v-btn>
          </div>

          <v-card-title
            :class="(isMobile)?'headline':'display-1'"
            class="indigo--text text--darken-4 font-weight-black pt-0 px-2 px-md-6"
          >{{post.title.rendered}}</v-card-title>
          <v-card-subtitle
            :class="(isMobile)?'body-2':'subtitle-1'"
            class="py-3 px-2 px-md-6"
            v-html="post.excerpt.rendered"
          ></v-card-subtitle>
          <v-card-actions class="px-2 px-md-6">
            <span :class="(isMobile)?'caption':'body-2'">{{ formatDate(post.date)}}</span>
            <v-divider class="mx-4 mt-0" inset vertical></v-divider>
            <span
              :class="(isMobile)?'caption':'body-2'"
              class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold"
            >Redacción</span>
          </v-card-actions>
          <v-card-text :class="(isMobile)?'pa-1':''">
            <v-row class="pa-0">
              <v-col cols="12" md="8" class="pa-0">
                <v-card-text v-html="post.content.rendered"></v-card-text>
                <div class="pa-5 grey lighten-5">
                  <RelacionadosTags :exclude="post.id" :relacion="post.tags" />
                </div>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="12" md="4" class="grey lighten-5 d-none d-md-block">
                <ListaNoticias :exclude="post.id" :categories="post.categories[0]" />
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import axios from "axios";
    import moment from "moment";

    import {mapState} from "vuex";

    import RelacionadosTags from "@/components/RelacionadosTags.vue";
    import ListaNoticias from "@/components/ListaNoticias.vue";

    export default {
      name: "Post",
      components: {
        ListaNoticias,
        RelacionadosTags
      },
      data: () => ({
        post: {},
        loading: false,
        error: false,
        laodingCategories: false,
        slug: "",
        categorias: []
      }),
      computed: {
        isMobile() {
          return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.width <= 768;
        }
      },
      methods: {
        async getPost() {
          await axios
            .get(
              `${this.urlApi}posts/?slug=${this.slug}&_embed`
            )
            .then(res => {
              this.post = res.data[0];
            })
            .catch( error => this.error=true)
            .finally(() => (this.loading = true));
        },

        async getCategorias() {
          await axios
            .get(`${this.urlApi}categories`)
            .then(res => {
              this.categorias = res.data.reduce((acc, value) => {
                acc[value.id] = value;
                return acc;
              }, {});
              this.laodingCategories=false;
            });
        },

       formatDate(date) {
          return moment(date).format("dddd DD [de] MMMM [del] YYYY");
        },

        setSlug() {
          this.slug = this.$route.params.slug;
        }
      },

      created(){
          this.$emit(`update:layout`, StandarLayout);
      },

      mounted() {
        //moment.locale("es");
        this.setSlug();
        this.getPost();
        this.getCategorias();
      }
    };
    </script>

    <style lang="scss">
    .post {
      .v-card__title {
        word-break: normal !important;
      }
    }
    </style>
```

- Ya actualicé VUE CLI a su versión más reciente y nada!
- Ya corregí mi código por si tenga errores de compilación y nada!
- Ya intente iniciar desde la consola de mi editor de textos (npm run serve) y no muestra errores solo se queda en 44%

Cualquier sugerencia me servirá para encontrar el error, todo mi trabajo esta estancado... Tantos días programando para nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo estás utilizando?

Comment: Estoy usando Windows 10

Comment: Solo se queda cargando y nada más pero ese problema es reciente porque días atrás estaba normal

Comment: Por qué en vez de utilizar el [vue ui] no utilizas la terminal de tu editor de texto y en ella lo inicias así te muestra el errores específico. [npm run serve]

Comment: Ya lo e intentado se queda paralizado en 45% y nada. Se queda congelado e probado cambiar de puerto igual se queda congelado.